# How can i parse BSON Timestamp in java

Tags: java, mongodb, parsing, bson

Hello guys i have this Bson Timestamp:

```
"ts" : { "$timestamp" : { "t" : 1562880169, "i" : 1 } }
```

How can i get the "t" and "i" values and parse them into variables in java.

I'm getting the Timestamp like this :

```
 BsonTimestamp timeStamp = (BsonTimestamp) currentDoc.get("ts");
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BsonTimestamp object has getInc and getTime and getInc methods to extract those values.
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/org/bson/types/BSONTimestamp.html

To get the time, you would do a timeStamp.getTime() and for 'i' you would do a timeStamp.getInc()

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject newObject = new JSONObject(bsonString);
System.out.println(newObject.get("t"))
```